# ChartistJS : Converting jQuery solution to AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, chartist.js

I am using Chartist JS for my charts in my Angular JS app. The issue is I am seeing [this](https://github.com/gionkunz/chartist-js/issues/119) here. There is a [JS bin](http://jsbin.com/wozabimiwi/1/edit?html,css,js,output) that highlights the issue. The author gives a [solution](http://jsbin.com/bawofakogu/1/edit?html,css,js,output) for it. The solution is doing DOM manipulations in Jquery which is easy to do. However with AngularJS the way you manipulate the DOM is via Directives. I have created a plunker [here](https://jsfiddle.net/saras_arya/nkz8ysme/) which highlights the same issue in Angular JS but I am confused as to how to put the solution provided by author into my Angular code. 
Here is the solution

```
$('[data-tab]').on('toggled', function (event, tab) {
    tab.find('.ct-chart').each(function(i, e) {
      e.__chartist__.update();
    });
});
```

**Edit**: As requested the JSFiddle is updated, so what I am trying to do is. I have three different tabs and three different graphs, whenever I click on them I should see the respective graph. To make the tab behavior possible I have written a basic code using scope and model. which facilitates the changing of tabs. The issue is that the chart is getting created for first or default tab but not for the second and third tab. There is a solution given by the author but I don't know how to implement that in AngualrJS

Comment: I checked your plunker, there is a function is undefined.  `getComparativeDriverData();` Please update your code, and it will be nice to post what you have done so far in the post.

Comment: Edit done @ShaohaoLin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using angular.element() method. So if you wish you use jquery in your angular code. You have to do this via angular.element method. But make sure to include jquery before angular in your index.html

> If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery
>   function. If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to
>   Angular's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or jqLite.

I did not know this. From here it was learning for me. Following advice of @pieterjandesmedt from [this](https://github.com/gionkunz/chartist-js/issues/119) post. I was able to do this. For other people who want to learn how this works. I have created a GitHub [repo](https://github.com/gionkunz/chartist-js/issues/119) which gives a solution to this issue. The link for problem is given in the question. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

the jQuery solution that you post is basically finding all the chart references and then doing DOM manipulation and call the `update()` function.

**The key is how to find the chart to update in Angular.**

In this case, you can assign a variable when you create a chart. For example:

```
var chart4 = new Chartist.Bar('#chart4', data1);
var chart5 = new Chartist.Bar('#chart5', data2);
```

Now you have the reference of the chart. All you have to do is to call `update()` function to render the chart again.

```
if (value === "allDrivers") {
  $scope.tab = "All";
  chart4.update();
}
```

Here is the [working plunker](https://jsfiddle.net/nkz8ysme/21/)

One thing I like to point out is: right now you need to double click the tab in order to see the chart is being rendered or you resize the browser window. I am still trying to find a way to fix this. But at least this approach gives you an idea how to convert the jQuery solution to Angular solution.

Comment: But why do we have to click twice? What is the logic behind this?

Comment: I guess the chart is rendered before the tab content is available.

Comment: I suspect it too. But the charts are not inside any function, they are in scope of the controller. So when the controller runs before the view. The view should already have the requisite components to load the chart. But it still doesn't. Makes me wonder, where I am thinking wrong

Comment: Actually, the chart is being drawn. It is just too small to see it. If you click the tab once, and resize the window. The chart will get resize and is visible. Because this behavior, I suggest you give it the chart with fixed height and width.

Comment: I tried giving it, but even that doesn't work... Why is the functionality working on the second click?  I tried giving two update functions, but that's not the case. Then what is that I am missing? So I see two ways here. Either I am able to give it fixed height and width which I tried and failed and the second is to programmatically replicate the behavior of the second click, which I don't understand. A little more direction is needed here